# How to convert C# MultipartFormDataContent to JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Does any one now how to convert `MultipartFormDataContent` to Newtonsoft `JObject`. And, is this possible at all?
I have tried:

`JObject.FromObject(multiPartContent)`,
or `JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(multiPartContent))`

But none of those work.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  `MultipartFormDataContent` is used to send multipart form data (usually a file) to a server; it isn't JSON.

Answer (score 1):

That will not be possible because if you look at the class it not a class that contains several variables that can be easily converted to a json object,it looks more like a method driven class where every method has a function, therefore it will most likely not get converted to json object.